# Concat Columns with NULL-values

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I want to concat two Columns in the TableAdapter Wizard of the VS Dataset-Designer.
The problem is that one column has NULL-Values and hence the concatination results in NULL regardless of the value of the other column.
I've found out that i must [SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx), which is a Database option. 
How can i change this setting in a TableAdapter Query Builder? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've solved it in the following way:

```
tabSparePart.SparePartName + ' ' + ISNULL(tabSparePart.SparePartDescription, '') AS LongSparePartName
```